# Event exchange rule in rabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have a game for social networks. In this game every player can get some bonus score for any action that he makes. All actions are publising to rabbit Mq in json like `{"action": "register", "player_id": 10, "action_id": 100}`.

I want to create 10 parallel workers to consume and proceed this actions. I have a strict condition that all events for player must be in the same queue. It means that I can't proceed events for player in parallel.

What is the right way to distribute my events to parallel queues?

I've already tried to add topic based on `player_id % queues_count` (remainder of the division) like `event_to_queue_9`, `event_to_queue_2` and so on. In this case I have two or three overflowed queues and others are empty. Is there better way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to provide the sharded routing key from the client (which I'd argue that's not optimal), you may want to have a look to [RabbitMQ Consistent Hash Exchange](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-consistent-hash-exchange)